# Data persistence in InfluxDB, using influxdb3

Tags: go, influxdb, influx-line-protocol

While persisting data in influx-db, there is a column name **Time** which is managed by influx itself. By default the format in which time stored is `2023-08-29T07:43:46.872Z`

I am trying to store the timestamp in Unix format, which is not happening.

I am using following module

https://github.com/InfluxCommunity/influxdb3-go

And below is my implementation in goLang to persist data in influx-db.

```
eventTime := time.Now().UnixNano()
timeSt := time.Now().UnixNano()
line := fmt.Sprintf("stat,avg=%f,max=%f eventTime=%d %d", 22.3, 40.3, eventTime, timeSt)

err = client.Write(context.Background(), []byte(line))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Here as the line protocol suggests having

`measurement, tagSet=value fieldSet=value timestamp`

here the timestamp is getting ignored. And following is stored in my influx-db

[image: Data stored in my influxDb]

Expectation is to have the Epoch in Time column.

Also a followup question - can we update the name of column **Time**?